# How to process items in a list 2 at a time in Dart

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await

I have a directory of videos that I want to compress by calling ffmpeg from Dart but I want to process 2 videos at a time.

```
import 'package:glob/glob.dart';
import 'dart:core';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final videoFiles = Glob('E:/camera/*.mov');
  var videos = videoFiles.listSync();
  var videosInQueue = 0;

  while (true) {
    if (videos.isEmpty) {
      print('No more videos to process');
      break;
    }

    if (videosInQueue < 2){
      print('\n$videosInQueue videos in the queue. Adding more...');
      var video = videos.removeLast();
      var videoInfo = await getVideoInfo(video);

      if (videoInfo['shouldProcess']) {
        videosInQueue += 1;
        var response = ProcessVideo(videoInfo['path'], videoInfo['outputName']);

        response.then((onValue) {
          videosInQueue -= 1;
        });
      }
    }else{
      continue;
    }
  }
}

Future<int> ProcessVideo(String path, String outputName) async {
  print('Processing $path');
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  return 200;
}
```

I tried using isolates but that just add additional complexity since I am not using dart to do the actual processing and I'm just making a system call to ffmpeg.

The **getVideoInfo** function returns a map with information on the video. **shouldProcess** is true if the **outputName** doesn't exists already. The output of this function would look like:

```
{
'shouldProcess':True,
'path': 'E:/camera/recording0023-10-12-2019.mov'
'outputName': 'E:/camera/done/recording0023-10-12-2019.mov'
}
```

When I run this code, it adds the first 2 videos to the queue, but it gets stuck in the while loop

Output:

```
0 videos in the queue. Adding more...
Processing E:/camera\recording0023-10-12-2019.mov

1 videos in the queue. Adding more...
Processing E:/camera\recording0024-10-12-2019.mov
```

I suspect that this code...:

```
response.then((onValue) {
          videosInQueue -= 1;
        });
```

isn't being called so videosInQueue never gets decremented. How can I correct this?